# Missing pom artefact even after installing dependancy with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I'm working through my errors one by one. Starting to get a grip with Maven now but I am a little stuck on this error:

> Failed to execute goal on project services: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project eu.billfold:services:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed
>   to collect dependencies at eu.sdk:sdk:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for eu.sdk:sdk:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
>   eu.billfold.myproject:root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://download.java.net/maven/2/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   java.net has elapsed or updates are forced

I recently cleared all the errors on the target "sdk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" which I installed locally with the "mvn install" command. When trying to install a new Maven build it can not seem to find it as required.

I have checked my .m2 local repo and the target JAR is indeed in there at this path:

.m2 > repository >eu > sdk > sdk > 1.0-SNAPSHOT > sdk-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Here is the POM dependancy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>eu.billfold</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>

    <modules>
        <module>support</module>
        <module>account</module>
        <module>bo-user</module>
        <module>campaigns</module>
        <module>currency</module>
        <!--<module>geolocation</module>-->
        <module>report</module>
        <module>payment</module>
        <module>mail-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.sdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from: junit-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from: easymock-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymockclassextension</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from: spring3-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from: mockito-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- from: slf4j-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring3-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaassist-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax-apis-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security3-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>eu.boms</groupId>
                <artifactId>geoip-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I am a little stumped?

Comment: Well. Is `${project.version} = 1.0-SNAPSHOT`?

Comment: yes:  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> within parent element. That should correct I believe?

Comment: Not exactly. Could you post your POM?

Comment: There is an additional folder I noticed towards the end of the path I specified,  1.0-SNAPSHOT - could this be it?

Comment: I think you are confusing several elements. Post your whole POM please.

Comment: Ok just edited to show it all, thanks.

Comment: Try: `mvn -U clean install`

Comment: Wow it works, it worked and yes the little -U was killing me. I actually figured this out eventually myself and it held me up for half a day. I have successfully built my entire multimode project and am happy now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments on the question I was missing the -U in the mv install command. I did have a dependency issue earlier but I couldn't check it was fixed without this command.

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be several causes to your problem.
Anyway, I note : "Failure to find eu.billfold.myproject:root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT ". It refers to your parent project :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>eu.billfold</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Maven dependencies resolution won't work properly if the parent (the root of your project) is not built.
Please build you parent project with "mvn install", and then retry to build your project eu.billfold:services.

Comment: Thank you I was stupidly missing this mvn -U clean install